# moving a train of points (cars)

Tags: matlab, simulation, point

We are trying to simulate moving cars using different coloured and sized points (car type 1 : red size 20, car type 2 : green size 40 and so on), the problem is if there was two cars of the same type they overlap where they should follow each other, this is the used code:

```
x = linspace(0,30,1000);
axis([0,20,-0.4,1.5]);
ax = gca;
h = hgtransform('Parent',ax);
type1=plot(-1,0.4,'s','Parent',h,'MarkerFaceColor','red','MarkerSize',20);
type2=plot(-1,0.4,'s','Parent',h,'MarkerFaceColor','green','MarkerSize',40);
car=[1 2 2 1 1];
for k = 1:10:700
    for i = 1:length(car)
       if(car(i)==1)
           set(type1,'XData',x(k),'YData',0.4);
           pause(0.1);
       elseif(car(i)==2)
           set(type2,'XData',x(k)-3,'YData',0.4);
           pause(0.1);
       end
    end
end
```

How to keep sequence that every (x=3) a new car start moving without deleting or over lapping the cars in front of it.

Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want below code.

```
x = linspace(0,30,1000);
axis([0,20,-0.4,1.5]);
ax = gca;
car=[1 2 2 1 1];
h = hgtransform('Parent',ax);
Ncar=length(car);

for n=1:Ncar %generate 5 cars having one type among type1 and type2
    if car(n)==1;
       types(n)=plot(-1,0.4,'s','Parent',h,'MarkerFaceColor','red','MarkerSize',20);
    else
       types(n)=plot(-1,0.4,'s','Parent',h,'MarkerFaceColor','green','MarkerSize',40);
    end
end

for k = 1:10:700 %plotting the cars sequencially
    for i = 1:length(car)  
           set(types(i),'XData',x(k)-3*(i-1),'YData',0.4);
       pause(0.1);
    end
end
```